# python POST a StringIO using poster

Tags: python, post, stringio, poster

Here is the situation:

I use PIL to process an image, then I save it to a StringIO object.
Now, I want to POST the StringIO object through poster.
But, I can't get the image in the request.FILES dict.
I have googled for a few hours, I found this question,
[python : post data within stringIO through poster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354589/python-post-data-within-stringio-through-poster)
I tried but don't work.

So, I read the poster source code and found it try to get the 'name' attribution of the file-like object param, but it seems like StringIO object doesn't have the 'name' attribution, So, the filename and filetype are None

```
if hasattr(value, 'read'):
    # Looks like a file object
    filename = getattr(value, 'name', None)
    if filename is not None:
        filetype = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]
    else:
        filetype = None

    retval.append(cls(name=name, filename=filename,
        filetype=filetype, fileobj=value))
else:
    retval.append(cls(name, value))
```

So, I specify the name attribution of StringIO object and it seems work fine.

```
im_tmp = Image.open(StringIO(bits))
//bits: the binary chars of a image
im_res = ImageAPI.process(im_tmp, mode, width, height)
//ImageAPI: a class that use PIL methods to process image
output = StringIO()
im_res.save(output, format='PNG')
output.name = 'tmp.png'
//I add above code and it works
call(url_str=url, file_dict={'file':output})
//call: package of poster
```

Did I do right? what's the right way to POST a StringIO object through poster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this commit](https://bitbucket.org/chrisatlee/poster/commits/34369b546aad46fe854abe578b86cac2b1a772c8?at=default), making the name optional was done *explicitly* to support passing in a `StringIO` object, but as you discovered that then skips detecting the mime type and defaults to `text/plain` instead.

Your approach then, is entirely correct. Simply set the `.name` attribute to goad `poster` into detecting a mime type.

The alternative is to use a better library to POST to the web. I recommend you look at [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/), which [supports multipart POSTing of files](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) out of the box, including a way to set the filename. The mimetype will be based on that explicit filename if passed in.

Comment: thanks, but the project is using poster and I cann't change the structure.